# Does the Panasonic Lumix DMC-FT2/TS2 have a tripod mount?

Tags: tripod

I'm looking at buying this camera, but can't find any specs or pictures that indicate whether there is a tripod mount.  Does anyone know?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This page](http://www.camera-catalog.com/compares/popular/panasonic_lumix_dmc-ft2_vs_panasonic_lumix_dmc-ft1) says that it has a tripod mount.

[Here](http://www.photographyblog.com/reviews/panasonic_lumix_dmc_ft2_review/) you can see a picture of the underside, showing the tripod mount.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it does. You can see the mount on [an image on this page](http://www.digicambuyer.co.uk/cameras/panasonic/dmc-ft2).

As a side note, I can't recall ever having seen a camera without one.